# Scroll to next section/class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to scroll to the next section on the page based on the viewport. I do not want to keep track of each element and if they have been visited, because if the user decides to scroll up again, it should just scroll to the next section anyway. Hence why I came up with this solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/w28tfnm9/

```
$("#scroll-down").on("click", function() {
    $(".section").each(function() {
        var isInViewPort = $(this).isInViewport();
        if (isInViewPort) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

However, I have a slight issue: It will not scroll to the first element. That makes sense, since I check if the current element is in the viewport, then I scroll to the `.next()` element, but I can't figure out how to solve this, without messing up what I already have. Is there a better way?

Instead of saying `.next()`, I essentially want it to go to the next `.section` element. Since it's not guaranteed the `.next()` element is a section, this is not a "good" solution.

Comment: why dont just put t as $(this).next('.section').offset().top

Comment: @RAHULSR Because `.next(".section")` wouldn't go search the child elements.

Comment: Oh, and it wouldn't solve my "won't scroll to first section" problem.

Answer (score -1):

So I ended up with a hack:

https://jsfiddle.net/w28tfnm9/3/

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($("body").scrollTop() < $(".section").offset().top) {
        hasScrolled = false;
    } else {
        hasScrolled = true;
    }
});
```

I basically iterate through each element, if `i === 0` it means I am at the top, but since I am trying to grab the next using `.get()`, I need to set the current iteration to `-1`. Works like a charm and "resets" when I scroll above the first element.

Comment: Your code is not working as expected . please check the code

Comment: @ankitverma Yes it is..? Check my fiddle.